# How to expand all columns for Get-AzReservation return array?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to get all information about my reservation and for that
I use `Get-AzReservation` cmdlet.

It returns the 7 columns as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.reservations/get-azreservation?view=azps-10.2.0).

But when I use `Export-Csv` and `Import-Csv` on that array and then check the imported array I get 56 columns.

How to show all the columns returned by the `Get-AzReservation` cmdlet without doing the csv step?

```
$reservation = Get-AzReservation -ReservationOrderId a87c1742-0080-5b4d-b953-8531ad46fdc8 -ReservationId cad6fef7-ae86-4d47-91d0-67c897934bfe

$reservation | Export-Csv -Path "res1.csv" -NoTypeInformation

$res1 = Import-Csv -Path "res1.csv"

$res1
```

I tried `-Expand` but it wants only `renewProperties` and returns an error.

Clearly the data is there because the csv has 56 columns but how to see it? Or at least be informed that I don't see all the columns because the documentation doesn't mention it. (`| ft -Wrap` from docu doesn't work)

Comment: ```$res | format-list *``` will give you a *vertical* list of properties rather than a table, but it will show you all the properties more clearly than a 56 column table would…

Comment: @mclayton - any idea why they don't mention the columns in the documentation? Also, it worked so you can put it as answer so I can accept solution.

Comment: Done. Also added a (very) short summary of the formatting settings PowerShell uses to display values - it’s a surprisingly big topic and there’s a lot more info available elsewhere…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, `$res | format-list *` will give you a vertical list of properties rather than a table, but it will show you all the properties more clearly than a 56 column table would.

The documentation shows the default results from “stringifying” the result of `Get-AzReservation` - PowerShell has a bunch of configuration settings that specify whether to default to formatting output as a table or a list, and also what properties to output for individual types of objects, and in this case it shows a table containing the columns shown in the documentation.

By using `| format-list *` you’re overriding the default display settings and telling PowerShell to format as a list and show *all* properties…